# How to send a Salesforce platform event from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, salesforce, force.com

I need help understanding how to authenticate and send data from AWS to the force.com API.

Specifically, I want to transform device data I receive in AWS into the Salesforce Platform Event format and send it to the Salesforce Platform Event API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Publishing a Platform Event on the force.com platform through their api works through essentially the same process as creating a record, and you can use either the Rest and SOAP api to do this.

A good overview can be found in the [Platform Events Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm).

As for authentication, there are a few options available. If your AWS application is going to have it's own SF license, the SOAP api's login method is pretty straightforward ([link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89423/obtain-enterprise-wsdl-via-curl/89436#89436)), otherwise, there are a collection of oAuth login flows available that you can reference in the [REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm).

Comment: I understand conceptually, but looking for a code sample as I don't get mechanically how to get the token from Saleforce, and then send it from Lambda each time I want to post. Thanks.